# Failed to submit form with multiple files and inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to build a form that can gather information if visitor do have interest.

As I search through the internet, a lot of result comes with ajax and formData, but what I got in console is: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.

I have tried new FormData() without anything in the brackets, and the console.log returns with blank data.

Right now I really have no idea what to do with it, except make the form simpler.
Please guide me through any problems you see in the codes below.

**HTML**

```
<section class="bg-light" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="container" id="theForm">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="theForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">*姓名: </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <lable for="">電話: </lable>
            <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <lable for="">*Email: </lable>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="OC" name="checkbox" class="form-check-input Checkbox" value="OC" checked>
            <lable>角色設計</lable>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="personal" name="checkbox" class="form-check-input Checkbox" value="personal">
            <lable>個人委託</lable>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="profile" name="checkbox" class="form-check-input Checkbox" value="profile">
            <lable>大頭貼</lable>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="cover" name="checkbox" class="form-check-input Checkbox" value="cover">
            <lable>書籍封面</lable>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="checkbox" class="form-check-input Checkbox" value="other">
            <lable>其他</lable>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <lable>參考附件
              <p>*可多選</p>
            </lable>
            <input type="file" id="file" multiple>
          </div>
          <br>
          <label for="detail">*詳細說明： </label>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="detail"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="text-right">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="取消">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" value="確認">
          </div>
        </form>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div id="Pic" class="col-md-7 bg-cover" style="background-image: url('images/makson-serpa-7KAInrNdG0U-unsplash.jpg'); top:0; bottom:0; position: absolute; height: 66vh"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Javascript/jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#theForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();//防止頁面跳轉
        var form = document.getElementById("theForm");
        var upfile = document.getElementById("file");
        for(const file of upfile.files){
            form.append("files[]", file);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: './php/process.php',
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$name =  $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$checkBoxes = $_POST["checkbox"];
$detail = $_POST["detail"];

$totalFile = if(is_array($_FILES)){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $value){
        $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
        $allow_ext = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif");
    
        if(in_array($file_name[1], $allow_ext)){
            $newName = md5(rand()).'.'.$file_name[1];
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $targetPath = "uploads/".$newName;
    
            move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);
        }
    }
}

$result = "姓名: '$name\r\n' 信箱: '$email\r\n' 電話: '$phone\r\n' 類別: '$checkBoxes\r\n' 檔案: '$totalFile\r\n' 描述: '$detail'";

echo $result;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending correct content type in when sending an ajax? usually to send files with http requests you need "multipart/form-data", which doesn't appear to be the case, try adding that in your ajax request,

Comment: @SyedNaeem Thanks for your comment, sir. I think the enctype attribute in the begin of the form tag is equal as contentType in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just append `[]` to the file name since you are using multiple attribute in your input field

from

```
<input type="file" id="file" multiple>
```

to

```
<input type="file[]" id="file" multiple>
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="bg-light" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="container" id="theForm">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="theForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          
          <div class="form-check">
            <lable>參考附件
              <p>*可多選</p>
            </lable>
            <input type="file[]" id="file" multiple>
          </div>
          <br>
          <label for="detail">*詳細說明： </label>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="detail"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="text-right">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="取消">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" value="確認">
          </div>
        </form>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

There won't be need for the loop to append the files to array:
this will no more be needed

```
var upfile = document.getElementById("file");
    for(const file of upfile.files){
        form.append("files[]", file);
    }
```

**Javascript/jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#theForm").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();//防止頁面跳轉

//remove this and directly access the form element below
//var form = document.getElementById("theForm");

$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: './php/process.php',
//change from this to
//data: new FormData(form),
//to
data: new FormData(this),
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
}
   });
 });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$name =  $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$checkBoxes = $_POST["checkbox"];
$detail = $_POST["detail"];
$allow_ext = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif");
//$files = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']);
//something like that to be used before processing files.

// Count # of uploaded files in array
$totalFile = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalFile; $i++) {

  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a file path
  if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
    $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
    // Get extension
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //check extension
    if (in_array($ext, $allow_ext)) {
      $newName = md5(rand()) . '.' . $file_name[1];
      $targetPath = "uploads/" . $newName;
    }
    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $targetPath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    } else {
      //handle failed file move
    }
  }
}


$result = "姓名: '$name\r\n' 信箱: '$email\r\n' 電話: '$phone\r\n' 類別: '$checkBoxes\r\n' 檔案: '$totalFile\r\n' 描述: '$detail'";

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sir. But <input type="file[]" id="file" multiple> makes the input to a blank text box witch looks like type="text".

Comment: @RickLee
sorry my bad 
suppose to be : 
`<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple>`
if it's solves your problem don't forget to mark as accepted answer.

Comment: It's okay. I think the reason why it says Failed to construct 'FormData': is because the id="theForm" exist both on the form tag and div tag. Definitely something I miss during programming, after remove the id on div, now it gives me the blank data. I suppose that means `<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple>` works as you mentioned above, also the problem goes to the php file for whatever cause it to send me nothing.  May be I should change the topic for the new problem.

Comment: @RickLee made some Edits to my answer you can check it out

Comment: Thank you so. You are a time saver. Now I just have to figure out how to move upload files to the folder I want.